# Vue Select how to bind 1 property to v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-select, vue-select

I've put v-model in v-select but it returns the whole object

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select - Using v-model</h1>
  <v-select v-model="selected" :options="options" value="id" label="labels">

  </v-select>  
  {{selected}}
</div>

    Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: [      
      {id: 1, labels: 'foo'},
      {id: 3, labels: 'bar'},
      {id: 2, labels: 'baz'},
    ],
    selected: '',
  }
})
```

this will result to this
[image]

is there a way to get the selected objects id only instead of the whole object? I've tried putting value="id" but still doesn't work.

Comment: which library are you using for v-select?

Comment: @DuongDang https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/

Comment: what are you exactly trying to return? Also, can you show us your dataobject so we can see how you have your `options` marked up? - Since `selected` is an object, you should be able to return the value you want by doing `{{ selected.id }}` (or whatever value you are returning

Comment: @MikeDiglio i want to put the selected objects id only in v-model, in this case it puts the whole object.. so in selected, it must have the value "1". instead of {id: 1, labels: foo}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option would be to use a `computed` property so you can manipulate `selected` to return your requested value:

```
computed: {
    selectedID: function () {
      return this.selected.id;
    }
  }
```

Working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzWPKO) with your example

Comment: As much as I really like the workaround usage of computed property here. I still don't know why it is preferred over selected.id though.

Comment: @NeonNatureEX it outputs just the same, but what i wanted was the idea because I'm using it on different purpose though..

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

`<v-select v-model="selected" :options="options" id=" {{selected.id}} " label="labels">` ?

This will bind the selected ID into your V-select.

Comment: please see my last comment in my post.

Comment: Yeah, you wanted to have 1 instead of {id: 1, labels: foo} , right? Using {{ selected.id }} instead of {{ selected }} will solve it if that's all you want though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by v-model by the way? Do you want to display the label, and get the id AS a value or set the id as ID of the v-select?

Comment: what i meant was, the value of selected itself must be 1 instead of the whole object.. so i would not do {{selected.id}}

Comment: value={{ selected.id }} will return 1 as a value instead of the whole object

Comment: @Jiel if you don't want to use `{{selected.id}}`, your other option would be to use a `computed` property and name it something like  `selectedID` and then you can have it just return the value. The issue is that vue-select stores your options as objects so it will always return that object when you bind it ->  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzWPKO

Comment: @MikeDiglio ahh yes, that is exactly what i wanted. please put this as your answer..

Answer (score 0):

@Jiel , here is the working demo

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected:'',
    options: [
      { id: 0, labels: 'Vegetables' },
      { id: 1, labels: 'Cheese' },
      { id: 2, labels: 'Fruits' }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    selectedID: function () {
      return this.selected.id
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select - Using v-model</h1>
  <v-select v-model="selected" :options="options" label="labels">
  </v-select>  
  selectedID : {{selectedID}}
</div>
```